# Match Owner to filepath using Bash/Perl from Array

Tags: bash, perl, search, find

I dont have any preference bash/perl etc for this. ( i'm not a developer but have experience with both )

I will have a list of File System Paths read recursively by a script to find large or old files - so lets imagine I have a File with list of paths files like:

- /fs1/john1a/test.conf
- /fs1/storage/maryfolder/test.1.txt
- /fs2/folder/john2a/full.txt

I have a list of names and emails ( in an array? )

- john,john@acme.com
- mary,mary@acme.com

I want to parse the file and send an email based on names in the list found in the paths.

So John will get 2 emails based on naming used:

- /fs1/"john"1a/test.conf
- /fs2/folder/"john"2a/full.txt

I am searching for solutions and will post if found.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And where you have problem? What is the question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl you could try something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %email_info = (
    john => 'john@acme.com',
    mary => 'mary@acme.com',
);

my $fn = 'list.txt';

my $regex = do { my $temp = join '|', map { quotemeta } keys %email_info; qr/$temp/ }; 
open ( my $fh, '<', $fn ) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    send_mail_to_user( $1, $email_info{$1}, $_ ) if /($regex)/;
}
close $fh;
```

Comment: Hi Hakon , thank you this was perfect and will let me build from there. I apoligise to others who posted comments around "What work have i done"  - I had lots of scripts which parsed arrays and did similar things , but not exactly like this. thanks again.